# batch file with echo findstr not working inside for loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, echo, findstr

I have multiple string that come from a reg query inside a for loop.
I want to validate for each of them if it has certain words and do actions if it has.
My code is this:

```
for /l %%g in (0 1 3) do (
        echo HOME%%g
        for /f "tokens=1,2,3*" %%h in ('reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%%g /v ORACLE_HOME') do (

            echo HOME%%g
            echo %%j
            echo %%j | findstr /I /R /C:"806"
            if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
                echo YES
            ) else (
                echo NO
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /C:".isuites."
            if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 (
                echo YES
            ) else (
                echo NO
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /I ora90
            if errorlevel 0 (
                echo YES
            ) else (
                echo NO
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /I forms10
            if errorlevel 0 (
                echo YES
            ) else (
                echo NO
            )



        )
    )
```

The problem is that is does not validates the string as seen in the output

```
HOME0
HOME0
ECHO is off.
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME0
d:\oracle\806
d:\oracle\806
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME1
HOME1
ECHO is off. 
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME1
d:\oracle\iSuites
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME2
HOME2
ECHO is off.
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME2
d:\oracle\ora90
YES
YES
d:\oracle\ora90
YES
YES
HOME3
HOME3
ECHO is off.
YES
YES
YES
YES
HOME3
D:\oracle\forms10g
YES
YES
YES
D:\oracle\forms10g
YES
```

Comment: the "ECHO %%J" is the ORACLE_HOME. It returns, in this case, 4 different ORACLE_HOMEs.

Comment: That information is of no help for us as we don't know what the variables **h**, **i** and **j** get on parsing the output of the command `reg query` by `tokens=1,2,3*`. `ECHO is off.` in the output is an indication that variable **j** is an empty string and therefore `echo %%j` is just `echo` on execution which results in printing status of echo into the console window.

Comment: The strings that should return in the req query are:
d:\oracle\806
d:\oracle\isuites
d:\oracle\ora90
d:\oracle\forms10g
The variable %%G is a counter that return HOME0, HOME1, HOME2 and HOME3
So, you should have, as and example:
HOME0
d:\oracle\806
The point is, for each HOME ...0, 1, 2, 3 ...test wich home there is in fact ...806, isuites, forms10g or ora90
Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some corrections are needed in your code

Change `for %%h` into

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%h in ('reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%%g /v ORACLE_HOME ^| find "REG_SZ" ') do (
```

That way, the `ORACLE_HOME` key name will be in `%%h`, the `REG_SZ` type in `%%i` and the folder in `%%j` (i supose this is what you intended)

With this done, the next problem is `errorlevel` checks

When a block of code (code inside parenthesis) is parsed, all variable reads are replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute the block. So, if you use `%errorlevel%` inside you block of code, as this variable read has been replaced with the value of the variable before starting to execute, you will not see the real value.

You can use delayed expansion (include `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of batch file) and change the syntax from `%errorlevel%` to `!errorlevel!` to indicate to the parser that the variable read should be delayed until the moment the command is executed.

Or you can use the `if errorlevel n ...` syntax. In this case you should remember that the condition will be true for any `errorlevel` value greater or equal than the indicated value.

That is, if `errorlevel` is 1, both `if errorlevel 1` and `if errorlevel 0` will be true. For this reason, the proper way of checking error level is to check from greater values to lower values

```
echo %%j | findstr .....
if errorlevel 1 (
    ...
) else (
    ...
)
```

So, your code should be something like

```
....
....
for /l %%g in (0 1 3) do (
        echo Testing HOME%%g
        echo ---------------------------------
        for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%h in (
            'reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%%g /v ORACLE_HOME 2^>nul ^| find "REG_SZ" '
        ) do (

            echo %%j | findstr /L /C:"806"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo NO
            ) else (
                echo YES
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /C:".isuites."
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo NO
            ) else (
                echo YES
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /I /C:"ora90" 
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo NO
            ) else (
                echo YES
            )

            echo %%j | findstr /I /C:"forms10"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo NO
            ) else (
                echo YES
            )

        )
    )
)
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

Some of the `HOMEn` will not be echoed if they does not exist in registry. To "solve" it, the error output from `req query` is included in the data to be parsed and it is tested if the string `ERROR:` is found.

```
for /l %%g in (0 1 3) do (
        echo Testing HOME%%g
        echo ---------------------------------
        for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%h in (
            'reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%%g /v ORACLE_HOME 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /L /C:"REG_SZ" /C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ" /C:"ERROR:" '
        ) do (
            for %%z in ("806" ".isuites." "ora90" "forms10") do (
                (if "%%h"=="ERROR:" (echo() else (echo %%j)) | findstr /i /c:"%%~z"
                if errorlevel 1 (
                    echo NO
                ) else (
                    echo YES
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The %%j is already returning the folder, that is in fact what is intended.
Regarding the errorlevel, I changed to your suggestion and the and the outpur is the same ...I get always YESs when it should return only one YES and 3 NOs for each of the ORACLE_HOMEs

Comment: If I change the %ERRORLEVEL% to !errorlevel! with the deplyedexpansion it just says that was unexpected at this time and wont run

Comment: @PedroSales, i've included a modified copy of your code.

Comment: If I may, the only problem with that new code is that the HOME0 is not being output ....

Comment: Again, thank you for your update.
The HOME0 is still not being tested, and it should be because it exists, d:\oracle\806, and the error is not returned

Comment: @PedroSales, do you see the "Testing HOME0" and four "NO" after it?

Comment: No, I olnly see the Testing HOME0, nothing else after it

Comment: Testing HOME0
---------------------------------
Testing HOME1
---------------------------------
NO
d:\oracle\iSuites
YES
NO
NO
Testing HOME2
---------------------------------
NO
NO
d:\oracle\ora90
YES
NO
Testing HOME3
---------------------------------
NO
NO
NO
D:\oracle\forms10g
YES

Comment: @PedroSales Are you running the last posted code, at the end of the answer?

Comment: Yes, the one with the ERROR test

Comment: @PedroSales What is the result of executing `reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0 /v ORACLE_HOME` (with the %%c changed to the adecuated value, of course)

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME0
    ORACLE_HOME    REG_EXPAND_SZ    d:\oracle\806

Comment: @PedroSales, your registry value types do not match what i have. Your values are `REG_EXPAND_SZ` while i have `REG_SZ`. Add a `/C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ"` to the findstr filter in the `reg query` of the `for %%h`

Comment: Well, I haven't noticed this difference, but I have in fact both, REG_EXPAND_SZ and REG_SZ
Can it be like this?
'reg query \\%%c\HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\HOME%%g /v ORACLE_HOME 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /I /C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ" /C:"ERROR:" ^| findstr /I /C:"REG_SZ" /C:"ERROR:" '

Comment: @PedroSales, no,  `findstr /I /C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ" /C:"ERROR:" /C:"REG_SZ"` Just one filter for any of the values

Comment: IT's perfect now. Thank you so much for your help